# Could not find method android() for arguments in Android Studio project

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

I am trying to do a grade sync on my android studio project and I keep getting this error in the title.  My build.gradle file is

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.
buildscript {
repositories {
    jcenter()
}
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.1'

    // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
    // in the individual module build.gradle files
}
}
allprojects {
repositories {
    jcenter()
}
}
task clean(type: Delete) {
delete rootProject.buildDir
}

android {
compileSdkVersion 24
buildToolsVersion '24.0.0'
}
dependencies {

}
```

My error message is

```
Gradle sync failed: Could not find method android() for arguments [build_aiwlctiq29euo9devcma4v4r7$_run_closure3@22efc0bc] on root project 'MyRadio
```

I have looked online and tried multiple solutions but nothing seems to work.  What does this even mean?  Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Actually you are editing wrong gradle file.

Comment: Put your android and dependencies to build.gradle in app folder. Not in root project folder.

Answer (score 8):

Move your android{} part to this file [image: build.gradle]

Answer (score 6):

[image: Edit this gradle file]
currently you are editing top level gradle file but you have to edit App level

> > add dependencies over there.

Answer (score 2):

**Each module** you add in your Android Studio Project `has its own build.gradle` file. Any dependencies that you want to add is added in associated module build.gradle file.
So in your case you have to add your dependencies in your app's build.gradle file.

Here is an image showing where you should add that.

[image: Build Gradle]

Answer (score 2):

Refresh gradle after deleting the below

```
android {
compileSdkVersion 24
buildToolsVersion '24.0.0'
}
dependencies {

}
```

It works for me

Comment: Strange solution! But it worked for me as well...Thank you :-)

Answer (score 1):

Check if your APP Level `Build.Gradle` is missing `Plugin`

then Add `apply plugin: 'com.android.application'`

in APP Level `Build.Gradle`

From My solution.