# Android studio starting issue on Windows

Tags: android, xml, android-studio, android-developer-api

I just installed android studio and updated the sdk. I created a new project, but it seems not to compile. There is a problem with gradle sync:

`Error:(29, 0) Could not find method android() for arguments [build_st17khxxb7irr63f8isja72t$_run_closure4@3d9ba855] on root project 'MyApplication' of type org.gradle.api.Project.`

This is my manifest file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

Some useless words because too much code

This is the build.gradle file:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        }
        dependencies {
            classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.3'
        }
    }
    allprojects {
        repositories {
            jcenter()
        }
    }
    task clean(type: Delete) {
        delete rootProject.buildDir
    }
    subprojects {
        ext {
            compileSdkVersion = 22
            buildToolsVersion = '25.0.1'
        }
    }
    android{
        compileSdkVersion 22
        buildToolsVersion '25.0.1'
        dexOptions {
            incremental true
        }
        compileOptions {
            sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_6
            targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_6
        }
    }
    dependencies {
        compile files('app/libs/junit-4.12-JavaDoc.jar')
    }
```

Comment: Please add your build.gradle file content.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I understand you are talking about a gradle build problem. If I understand it right, there is an easy fix.

1. Open gradle.build
2. Find android {
3. Paste in this code below it:

   `compileSdkVersion 24
   buildToolsVersion "23.0.3`

   It should look like this then:

   `android {
     compileSdkVersion 24
     buildToolsVersion "23.0.3"`

Answer (score 0):

[Could not find method android() for arguments in Android Studio project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40012866/could-not-find-method-android-for-arguments-in-android-studio-project)

**This link will help you to solve your build.gradle problem.**

Answer (score 0):

`apply plugin: 'com.android.application'`

`android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.0"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.myapplication"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 25
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }`
    `buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}`

`dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })`
    `compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.0.1'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}`