# Is Android documentation wrong about adding android block to top-level build.gradle

Tags: android, gradle

https://developer.android.com/training/testing/unit-testing/local-unit-tests
clearly states

> ...adding the following configuration in your project's **top-level
>    build.gradle file**:

```
android {
    ...
    testOptions {
        unitTests.returnDefaultValues = true
    }
}
```

But doing so results in an error:

> Could not find method android() for arguments [...] on root project
>   '...' of type org.gradle.api.Project.
>
> Open File

When researching that error:

I find several existing StackOverflows that indicate it is wrong to add adroid{} to your top-level build.gradle file.

[Could not find method android() for arguments in Android Studio project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40012866/could-not-find-method-android-for-arguments-in-android-studio-project)

> In your top-level file, you can't define an android block.

[Could not find method android() for arguments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37250493/could-not-find-method-android-for-arguments)

> In your top-level file you can't define an android block

**Does that mean the Android documentation is wrong?**

If not, please help me to understand.

Comment: OK so which file did you *actually* add the `android` block into?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Good finding. 
Yes it's wrong, since there is no `android` method in lot level gradle file.

I guess they meant **project wide** gradle file, that should be `app/build.gradle`.

Also [here in documentation](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/#top-level) you can see that top-level gradle file just configures all modules.