# Could not find method android() for arguments [build_d9be98ivwpt3s3b6xyy0t65je$_run_closure2@b475224]

Tags: android, android-studio

I've got this error [Android studio error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D4PqN.png)

I can't understand this error, please someone provide a solution to this.

Comment: Possibly duplicated
[Link1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40012866/could-not-find-method-android-for-arguments-in-android-studio-project/40013029) [Link2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37250493/could-not-find-method-android-for-arguments)

Answer (score 0):

Add your android block into app/build.gradle file not build.gradle which in project root direcotry.

Comment: how to do this please explain

Comment: There are 2 build.gradle files ,one is in project root directory and another is in app/src directory,you need add android block in app/src/build.gradle not in root_path/build.gradle.